# ExtJS: Get operation.error on beforeload store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this ExtJS store, loaded remotely with Ajax:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'targetNamesStore',
    fields: ['id', 'text'],
    proxy: { type: 'ajax', url: 'test.php' },
    listeners: {
        beforeload: function(store, operation) {
            console.log(operation);
            console.log('error: ' + operation.error);
        }
    }
});
```

Along with this php code on the server side:

```
<?php
echo json_encode([
    'success' => false,
    'msg' => 'Some details about the error.',
    'metaData' => ['root' => 'data', 'messageProperty' => 'msg']
]);
?>
```

I would like to get the details about the error, which appears to be included in the `operation` object. But when I try to get it with `operation.error`, it's `undefined`:

[image: console output]

The others `operation` parameters (ie `success`, `limit`, ...) are correctly accessible. Same thing with `operation['error']` and `operation.getError()`.

I don't understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The `beforeload` event is called before the request is sent to the server, so the error is not yet available in the operation object.

The object you log into browser console is modified in-place during the operation, and when you look at it in browser console, you only see the state that it has at the time you look at it.

In Standard ExtJS, there is no event that is thrown between receiving the data and loading it into the store. You can add one if you have to.

I did so by overriding the function `Ext.data.reader.Json.getResponseData` and/or `Ext.data.reader.Json.readRecords` in various projects.

E.g. in one project I added output of error messages sent by the server to a message box:

```
readRecords: function(data) {
    var me = this,
        caption = 'Generic error',
        message = 'The server reported an error, but did not provide any details.';
    if (me.getSuccessProperty()) {
        if(!data || me.getSuccess(data)===false) {
            if(data.Message) message = data.Message;
            if(data.Caption) caption = data.Caption;
            Ext.Msg.alert(caption,message);
        }
    }
    return me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

but you could also do the following, which would be more in style with ExtJS (all following code is untested and without warranty):

```
readRecords: function(data) {
    var records = [];
    if(this.fireEvent('beforereadrecords', this, data)!==false) records = this.callParent(arguments);
    this.fireEvent('readrecords', this, data, records);
    return records;
}
```

and would allow you to add these listeners to the reader:

```
type: 'json',
rootProperty: 'test',
listeners: {
    beforereadrecords: function(data) {
        // beforereadrecords is cancelable, like all beforesomethingsomething events.
        if(...) return false;
    },
    readrecords: function(data, records) {
        records[1].set("something", "something else")
    }
}
```